# Satisfy std::ranges::range concept

Tags: c++, range, c++-concepts

In the upcoming C++20 ranges there will be the [range concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) with the following definition:

```cpp
template< class T >
concept range = __RangeImpl<T&>; // exposition-only definition

template< class T >
concept __RangeImpl = requires(T&& t) {
  ranges::begin(std::forward<T>(t)); // equality-preserving for forward iterators
  ranges::end  (std::forward<T>(t));
};

template< class T >
concept __ForwardingRange = ranges::range<T> && __RangeImpl<T>;
```

Translating this to plain English I'd say that the only requirement for a type to satisfy the range concept is to be callable with ranges::begin and ranges::end.

However if I create an empty type with just begin and end a static assertion on the range concept fails?

```cpp
namespace ranges = std::experimental::ranges;

struct A {
  void begin() {}
  void end() {}
};

static_assert(ranges::range<A>);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The meaning of "exposition-only" is what you are apparenly missing. It's not a real definition. Read the rest of the linked page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [[range.access.begin]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.access.begin): (emphasis mine)

> The name `ranges​::​begin` denotes a [customization point
>   object](https://eel.is/c++draft/customization.point.object). The
>   expression `ranges​::​​begin(E)` for some subexpression `E` is
>   expression-equivalent to:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if `E` is an lvalue, `decay-copy(E.begin())` if it is a valid expression **and its type `I` models
>     `input_­or_­output_­iterator`**.
> - [...]

With your `A`, `A.begin()` is of type `void`, which can't possibly be an iterator.  Therefore, `ranges::begin(std::declval<A>())` is invalid.